# Angularjs Routing Issue with url type:- localhost:3000/x/007

Tags: angularjs, express, routes, pug, angular-routing

express.js routing:-

```
app.get('/x/:id', function (req, res){
        var id = req.params.id;
        console.log('/:id ' + id);
    res.render('app');
});
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
        var name = req.params.name;
            console.log('came to partials:' + name);
        res.render('partials/' +name);
});
```

angular routing:-

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/x/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home',
        controller: 'questionCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

app.jade

```
body
    <div> inside app </div>
    <div ng-view> </div>
```

Presuming `home.jade` file is in `partials` folder. and we go to url `localhost:3000/x/007` we should open `app.jade` and inside ng-view we should view `home.jade`.

As expected app.jade is rendered. But the file 'home.jade' does not render. The url does not change to `localhost:3000/login` thus the route inside angular is indeed activated. What is preventing 'home.jade' to be rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following express.js route works:-

```
app.get('/x/partials/:id', function (req, res){
          // var id = req.params.id;
        console.log('x:id');
    res.render('partials/home');
});
```